# ASP.Net EventLog Error while running the project

Tags: asp.net

[image]I am getting the below error when i am running the ASP.Net project.

> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

I have tried running `regedit.exe` going to system and security folders and gave full control to all the users in my system but still no luck.....could any one tell me any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account that the website is running under does not have permissions to read the security event log.

Either grant it permissions or change it to an account that has these permissions.

In IIS 7/7.5 you can go to the Advanced Settings of the Application Pool to find out and change the Application Pool Identity.

Comment: Can you be more detail, what i need to do after going to Advance options of the application pool

Comment: @S.. - Look at application pool identity - that's the account that the web application is running under. This is where you can also change it to a more privileged account.

Comment: Oded...The framework it is showing in the advanced pool is 4.0 but i am using 2008 which is 3.5. I remember i have installed 4.0 on my system long back and un installed it...will that cause a prblem?

Comment: @S.. - It shouldn't, as 4.0 features are supposed to be backwards compatible.

Comment: @Oded Sorry to bug u...i am new to this, please c my edits to the q.....i have attached a screen shot of what i c in the Application pool....

Comment: @S.. - See the Advanced Settings link to the right? Select the correct application pool and click that link.